# Height of display block div goes over wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper .window and would like .window-content to have the full height of it, minus .window-titlebar and .window-option-bar. However when I put height: 100%, the .window-content will overflow over the wrapper. How do I avoid this?

```css
.window {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
    width: 60%;
    height: 70%;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 0px #000 inset, 1px 1px 0px 0px #FFF inset, -2px -2px 0px 0px #868A8E inset;
  background-color: #C2C5CA;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.window-titlebar {
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000080, #0992ec);
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
    height: 18px;
}
.window-option-bar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 5px 3px 8px 2px;
}
.window-option {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
.window-option:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px 0px #000 inset, -1px -1px 0px 0px #FFF inset;
}
.window-content {
    display: block;
    width: 98.5%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px 0px #000 inset, -1px -1px 0px 0px #FFF inset;
    background-color: #FFF; 
    overflow: scroll; 
}
```

```html
    <div class="window menu-context" id="home-window">
        <div class="window-titlebar"></div>
        <div class="window-option-bar">
          <a class="window-option">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <div class="window-content">
          test 
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: You .window-content takes height 100% so exactly the height of his container .window ) so you have to calculate the height 100% minus the other divs and the scrollbars... try calc(100% - 50px) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add this code

```css
.window {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.window-content {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px; //only if u prefer for better styling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add this line of code in the .window selector.

```
.window { 
/*Add this line*/
overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: This would snap off the bottom of my content, though, that's not what I want